# Adding a json dictionary into another json dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have such a code statement:

```
def add_names(req, names, firstnames, middlenames, lastnames, genders, e_mails, phone_numbers, locations, indata):
        data = []
        for a in range(len(names)):

                nxt = {"name": names[a], "profile_id": indata["profile_id"], "firstname": firstnames[a], "middlename": middlenames[a], "lastname": lastnames[a],
                       "e_mail": e_mails[a], "phone_number": phone_numbers[a], "location": locations[a], "sex": genders[a],
                       "user_id": indata["user_id"], "updated_by": indata["username"]}

                cpnxt = nxt
                del cpnxt['profile_id'], cpnxt['user_id'], cpnxt['updated_by']
                nxt.update({"jsondata": cpnxt})
                data.append(nxt)

        qs = "insert into persons (id, name, user_id, profile_id, firstname, middlename, lastname, e_mail, phone_number, location, sex, updated_by) values "
        qs += "(DEFAULT, %(name)s, %(user_id)s, %(profile_id)s, %(firstname)s, %(middlename)s, %(lastname)s, %(e_mail)s, %(phone_number)s, %(location)s, %(sex)s,"
        qs += " %(updated_by)s) returning id"
        res = db_add_list(req, qs, data)
        return res
```

Here, basically I get list values as parameters, and put the list values into the json dictionary called `nxt{}`, and add them into the database by using the query `"qs"` through `db_add_list()` function.

Now, what I want to do is; I want to add a json dictionary into the `nxt{}` dictionary. My dictionary will be the subset of `nxt{}` dictionary, which involves only some values of `nxt{}`.

I want to do that with this code, but I get such a weird output:

```
nxt = {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {'e_mail': '', 'firstname': 'John', 'jsondata': {...}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}, 'lastname': 'Smith', 'location': '', 'middlename': '', 'name': 'John Smith', 'phone_number': '', 'sex': 'M'}
```

How can I manage to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your `nxt` dictionary and add your new subset dictionary to it.

```
nxt.update({"new_dic": my_new_dic})
```

Comment: it is weird but there is a strange loop in updating the dict.

Comment: can u update your code? so i can see what u did there.

Comment: @yusuf Sorry for interrupt, the problem is with your key ```jsondata```, you're updaing same key values every time, you should change ```jsondata``` name in for loop iteration like ```jsondata1```, ```jsondata2``` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a key value pair for the `nxt` dictionary. like this:

```
nxt['subset'] = {'key': 'value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions described earlier work, i used pythons shell to show you.

```
In [1]: next = {}

In [2]: indexer = {}

In [3]: next['indexer'] = indexer

In [4]: upd = {}

In [5]: next.update({'upd' : upd})

In [6]: next

Out[6]: {'indexer': {}, 'upd': {}}
```